# Provide download link for Java when not installed

Tags: java, applet

I'm writing a Java applet for a small game. When a user doesn't have Java installed, I would like to provide some sort of help. Automatically downloading Java is most likely not an option. How would I go about detecting if Java is installed, and showing a OS-appropriate download button if it's not?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: *"Automatically downloading Java is most likely not an option."* Why not?

Comment: I assume it would be a big security risk for the user to have software download automatically.

Comment: You assume wrong in this case.  While (largely) automatic, the user is prompted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [JNLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#Java_Network_Launching_Protocol_.28JNLP.29) (also called Java Web Start). Here are a couple tutorials:

- [Deploying a Java Web Start Application](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html).
- [Deploying an applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html)

What's nice about JNLP is that you don't have to code anything, it's already been done for you. And it allows for the automatic download of a JRE if it's not installed.

Comment: Note that JWS will fail if *no* Java is installed.  It will only be able to upgrade an existing JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Use [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to ensure that a suitable JRE is installed (and then it will write the applet element).